# Django collectstatic giving no errors. But staticfiles not loading on website with both debug true and false. Files on S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

**Intro:** I have made my application in Django I am trying to get my static and media files hosted in aws s3. My Django project is on `AWS Lambda` and `AWS Api gateway` using `Zappa`.  below is my settings.py

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I then created a file in my project folder the same as my manage.py called `aws_storage_classes.py`

Below are the contents of my file `aws_storage_classes.py`

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage    

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
```

**Below are my `urls`**

```
if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also in my settings.py

> **DEBUG = False**

When I do `python manage.py collectstatic` all the staticfiles are downloaded and I don't get any errors. But when go on admin page the static files are not uploaded. See images below

> Below is the image of my S3 bucket

[image]

> Below is what is inside the static folder

[image]

> Static files not loading

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/style.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJHJGHJGJGJGJJGJGJMHIFQ&amp;Signature=yfS3%2BvA0q15aUxw7OBySuQWZfjg%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdgljdaksfgdjsgfkjertert;hre;thtires=151232173">
```

> Updated settings.py

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Below is the link after adding `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://django-static-media.s3.amazonaws.com/static/style.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAGGGGGGGGGMHIFQ&amp;Signature=6gFQTsOSDFSDFA%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=FQoGZvwbJhd9amp;Expires=1549168642">`

Still staticfiles not loading

I have given my user full s3 access so I don't think I should need the below. Also I was able to successfully add the static files in the S3 and it is not giving me any permission related errors.  still trying it out as per a suggestions below

Below are my permissions
I tried to give permission to lambda function but it gives me the bellow error

[image]

[image]

> After changing the static and media URLS

[image]

Comment: Did you also check your inodes with `df -i`?

Comment: Are the files in a private bucket? If so then, have you assigned role to Lambda to access the S3 bucket?

Comment: @Rakib I tried to do that however I am getting an error saying `Invalid principal in policy`

Comment: @Rakib Also I have given my user full S3 permission. Would I still need to create a bucket policy. Also I am not getting any errors in collect static. So it was able to put my static files in the bucket

Comment: I mean, go to IAM. Create a new role for Lambda and assign S3FullAccess to the role. Then assign the role to your Lambda function.

Comment: Check the networking tab of the dev tools in your browser.  Look at the URLs of the static assets that are being requested.  Are they correct?  What is the response you get for those requests?  That will be your best clue as to what's going on.  It sounds like you aren't having trouble uploading the files, but they do need to have public read access in order to be accessible from your browser.

Comment: @DanielHawkins Is it safe to give your S3 bucket public read access. Also I have added my link to the static urls above too

Answer (score 3):

I can see `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` not setup correctly.

change

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
```

To

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
```

It should work.

The following link has a very good explanation.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. but that's not it I actually hardcoded the static and media urls too. I made your changes I have added image above

Comment: @MarcoBianchi check out the link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: That's the 1st blog I read on this topic . For the time being I have commented out `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY")`
`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET_KEY")` It seems to be a temperory fix till I figure out the permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with me it was a ACL issue. I could only get collectstatic to run if I set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL=None but then all the files would be set to private by default and couldn't access them from the app.

To fix I had to change the S3 bucket Object Ownership to Bucket owner preferred so that it accepted the public-read ACL.